# I want to display variable 'b[i]' instead of 'x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue'. but either 'myFunction' or document.write(b[i]) seems not working

Tags: javascript, html, xml, function

I defined function 'myFunction(a, b)', and try to use it to convert a value from xml file to create new variable 'b', then write it in the table. but, either myFunction or document.write(b[i]) not work. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
<!-- Request DATA -->
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/xml/352438?res=3hourly&key=[value],false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

<!-- Write Table header -->
    var tableHeaders = ["Time", "Temp"];
    document.write("<table><tr>");
    for (i=0; i<tableHeaders.length;i++)
    { 
    document.write("<th>");
    document.write(tableHeaders[i].bold() + "&#160;&#160;&#160;");
    document.write("<\/th>");
    ;
    }document.write("<\/tr>"); 

<!-- Write DATA -->
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Rep");
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {                      
        var b[i] = myFunction(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue, 0.001);    //<--- NOT WORKING
        document.write("<tr><td>" +b[i] + "<\/td>");                   //<---NOT WORKING 

        //document.write("<tr><td>" +x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<\/td>");
        document.write("<td>" + x[i].getAttribute("T") +"&#176;C"+"<\/td>");   //temp
        document.write("<\/tr>");
    } document.write("<\/table>");

</script>function defining <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function myFunction(a, b) {
return a * b;
};
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use `document.write`; see the warning in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29). Don't use global variables; place your code in a self executing function instead. Don't modify the DOM at each step of a loop; update a string variable and modify the DOM at the end.

Comment: The error shows "Type of input is not xml". I am not clearly sure what the error means. And, why shouldn't I use document.write? I am trying to display the variable value of 'b' in the table. If not document.write, what do I use?

Comment: `document.write` is bad because of the warning in the spec I linked. You should use `innerHTML` or DOM methods instead.

Comment: thanks. problem solved by using innerHTML:)!

Comment: Worthing noting though that for some things, *document.write* is pretty useful. :-)

Comment: Remove the HTML comments from the script, they should **never** be used inside a script element. For historical reasons, they are tolerated as the first non–blank line of a script, but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

`myFunction` is not defined at the time the previous code runs. Move your myFunction declaration earlier.

Comment: Note this happens because the function is defined in another `script` element. If it was in the same, it would work because of hoisting, even if it was declared after its calls.

Comment: I put myFunction in the beginning, before 'Request Data'. Still not working.

Comment: The error appears "Type of input is not xml": I put the part of ' function myFunction(a, b) ... }; ' before <!-- Request Data -->. I inserted it in one script. Still not working.